# Php CURL response non-html code

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl to connect to `http://www.gumtree.com/search?q=bmw&category=all` but I am unfortunately getting this non-HTML response :

`moÛ6ÞO¹9Ø”`‘eÙÎšH¶‡¾nÀŠ¢@“íCQ´x’ØP¤FÒVÜ4ÿ}GÉiÔ$[ƒ  ñx÷Üû3û‘ëÌmk„ÒUr1+‘ñÅ¬BÇ +™±èæƒ³ÓWáñ Ú‘«p>ØljmÜ�2­*bkwåœãFd¶‡CJ8Ádh3&qGÆ`

I am using this code :

```
 $cookie_file="C:\Users\Yasha\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\cto2_gumtree.txt";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.gumtree.com/all/uk/daewoo");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);   // Cookie management.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

now if i connect to `http://www.gumtree.com/` or `http://www.gumtree.com/all` it works,

any advice would be appreciated

Comment: I dunno ? how to check it? and how to decode it to html code?

Comment: I decoded it using gzdecode and it is giving me an error 500 - Gumtree is broken

Comment: Some heavy cookies there.. But `curl` from the command line just succeeds here, and the to the point headers are just `Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8` & `Transfer-Encoding:  chunked`. (BTW: `Server GumBackend is not blacklisted
Server: GumBackend`.

Comment: :( you don't think there is any solution for it ?

Comment: Ah, for PHP: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Really? You need this?');`. Lousy browser-sniffing servers there... It's a problem on their side, but we can work around it by supplying a bogus user-agent.

Comment: wow thank you buddy it works! yeah they have very lousy structure put this as an answer so I will accept it as a solution

Comment: but one second how did you know that they don't have a useragent in the browser sniffing servers ? or you just tried ?